# how to autofit the columns in csv file using asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to export the values from datatable to csv format.My code works fine but as the column values are large it comes down to the next line.hence full alignment is getting changed.Below is my code.Please help.

```
        System.Data.DataTable dtMainSQLData = new System.Data.DataTable();

        da.Fill(dtMainSQLData);

        // Create the CSV file to which grid data will be exported.
        string filename = "Report";
        string test_Filepath = "C:\\Desktop\\";
        string file1 = filename + "_" + String.Format("{0:dd}", DateTime.Today) + String.Format("{0:MMMM}", DateTime.Today) + String.Format("{0:yyyy}", DateTime.Today) + ".csv";
        string new1 = test_Filepath + file1;
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(new1);
        if (file.Exists == true)
            file.Delete();

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new1, false);

    //First we will write the headers.

    int iColCount = dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
    {
        sw.Write(dtMainSQLData.Columns[i]);
        if (i < iColCount - 1)
        {
            sw.Write(",");
        }
    }
    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);


    // Now write all the rows.

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtMainSQLData.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
            {
                sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
            }
            if (i < iColCount - 1)

            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    }
    sw.Close();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your complaint is with Excel not with CSV. You will need to look at delimiting your cells properly, try and use something more exotic than a comma, for example the '|' character.